# Using VBA to find related records and inserting into report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a small database with a few tables. Since I can't share it for a number of reasons here's the gist:

1. Main Table: Customer Issues Table
2. Additional Tables: Junction Tables and the other tables needed for the Many-To-Many relationships.
3. Queries setup to link the main table to the other tables via the Junction Tables.

It all works fines, no issues. The Forms with subforms works great and the data is being stored fine.

Reports also work using the subreports, but the standard layouts are causing the problem, its making the reports way too long because they list outputs in a column. For example, each customer issue has a place for us to link it to "tags". These "tags" or "keywords" are in one of the many-to-many relationships so I can force some sort of integrity and consistency. When I create the subreport it just list the tags as you'd expect:

```
Tags:
Blue
Red
PC
Video Card
Main Board
Windows
Linux
etc.
```

What I want to do is list them this way:

```
Tags: Blue, Red, PC, Video Card, Main Board, Windows, Linux, etc.
```

My thought was to use VBA to do the above, something like this (not code, just structure):

```
SET VARIABLE TO OUTPUT OF DO COMMAND: RUN QUERY USING WHERE CLAUSE FOR THE CURRENT ISSUE ID

LOOP THROUGH THE VARIABLE TO CREATE A STRING OF THE TAGS FOUND

OUTPUT THE STRING CREATED IN THE LOOP TO THE REPORT
```

Just not sure the best way to go about this and was hoping any VBA/MS ACCESS experts could point me in the right direction.

I haven't tried anything yet, just looking for a place to start - if this is even possible. I am seeing conflicting reports on using recordsets in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I have a VBA function joining values from a query into a string

```vb
Public Function JoinFromRecordset(DataSourceName As String, Optional Delimiter As String = ";", _
                                  Optional Columns As Long = 1) As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, s As String, col As Long

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(DataSourceName, dbOpenForwardOnly)
    Do Until rs.EOF
        For col = 0 To Columns - 1
            If s = "" Then
                s = Nz(rs(col))
            Else
                s = s & Delimiter & Nz(rs(col))
            End If
        Next col
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close: Set db = Nothing
    JoinFromRecordset = s
End Function
```

The first parameter is either the name of a table or query or a complete SELECT statement. The second a delimiter (in your case that would be `", "`). It uses always the first column of the result unless you specify a number of columns that you want to include.

You would get the string like this:

```vb
s = JoinFromRecordset("SELECT TagName FROM <link cust with tags here> WHERE cust_id=" & me!customerID, ", ")
```

Well, I don't know how to formulate the query exactly since I don't know your tables, but you get it.

There are different ways on how you can integrate it in your report:

- Use it a Control Source of a TextBox (`=JoinFromRecordset("SELECT ...`).
- Assign it to a TextBox or Label in the VBA behind a report (e.g. in a Format event).
- Use it directly in a Query.

---

I have also another version for ADODB if you prefer it over DAO:

```vb
Public Function JoinFromRecordset(DataSourceName As String, Optional Delimiter As String = ";", _
                                  Optional Columns As Long = 1) As String
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, s As String, col As Long

    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open DataSourceName, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    Do Until rs.EOF
        For col = 0 To Columns - 1
            If s = "" Then
                s = Nz(rs(col))
            Else
                s = s & Delimiter & Nz(rs(col))
            End If
        Next col
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    cnn.Close: Set cnn = Nothing
    JoinFromRecordset = s
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try today! In my head I knew exactly how I would tackle this using PHP and MySQL with a web front end (thought probably janky compared to pros) - but none the less, this is pretty close to how I was thinking anyways. I will report back Olivier!

Comment: Well, it didn't work. Probably because I am a boob.  
  
Ultimately, the query that needs to be passed is:  
  
SELECT Tag, IssuesID FROM IssuesXTags WHERE IssuesID = 1  
  
Where 1 would be pulled from the current record set in the report; they are all bound to the IssuesID itself.  
  
I set a text box control to =JoinRecordset("SELECT Tag, IssuesID FROM IssuesXTags WHERE IssuesID=" & [IssuesID]) and the text box gave me #ERROR? - unfortunately, I can't figure out how to capture the error properly to see what its saying.

Comment: The name is `JoinFromRecordset`